# Integration to Gamma Function?

Tags: calculus, integration

I need to show that

$$\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}\theta^{-\tau(\alpha_1 + \alpha_2) - 1}e^{-\theta^{-\tau}\left(y^{\tau} + \delta^{\tau}\right)}\text{ d}\theta = \dfrac{\Gamma\left(\alpha_1 + \alpha_2\right)}{\tau\left(y^{\tau} + \delta^{\tau}\right)^{\alpha_1 + \alpha_2}}\text{,}$$
where each constant above is positive.

I know the definition of $\Gamma(x)$, but I don't find that useful here. I also know that 
$$\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}x^{n}e^{-ax}\text{ d}x = \dfrac{\Gamma\left(n+1\right)}{a^{n+1}}$$
for positive $n$ and $a$, but I don't see how this can be applied here.

**Edit**: I forgot about a comment someone gave me about this problem: "The solution in the solution manual is correct, although it leaves out the step of a very messy calculus change of variables in an integral in order to get $\Gamma(\alpha_1 + \alpha_2)$ to appear."

Comment: Should that be a $y$ or $x$ in the denominator of the right hand side for the first integral

Comment: Oh, that should be a $y$. Thanks!

Comment: You could almost make the substitution for $u=\theta^{-\tau}$ are you sure the first integral is completely correct?

Comment: That's what this solutions manual says.

Comment: I mean the integrand

Comment: Yes, I double-checked. This solutions manual is very frustrating, as it does not explain its steps. I did forget about a comment someone gave me about this problem until now: "The solution in the solution manual is correct, although it leaves out the step of a very messy calculus change of variables in an integral in order to get $\Gamma(\alpha_1 + \alpha_2)$ to appear."

Comment: I don't see why we can't make the substitution $x=\theta^{-\tau}$.

Comment: @Gina - I almost have it after trying the substitution. I can't figure out where the $\dfrac{1}{\tau}$ comes from.

Comment: The problem I saw was that the exponent for theta is $-\tau(a_1+a_2)-1$ instead of $-\tau(a_1+a_2-1)$. Maybe I'm missing something though

Comment: Did you forgot to substitute $d\theta$? $\frac{dx}{d\theta}=-\tau\theta^{-\tau-1}$ so $d\theta=\frac{dx}{-\tau\theta^{-\tau-1}}$.

Comment: Wow, this integral is awful. I still haven't solved it. Thank you @Gina, I did forget to substitute $\text{d}\theta$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a change of variables to eliminate the complicated term in the exponential:

$$x = \theta^{-\tau}$$

and set $a = y^{\tau} + \delta^{\tau}$. Given this, we have

$$dx = -\tau \theta^{-\tau - 1} d\theta$$

This leads to

$$\frac{dx}{- \tau x} = \theta^{-1} d\theta$$

Grouping appropriately, the integral is now

\begin{align*}
\int_0^{\infty} x^{-(\alpha_1 + \alpha_2)} \left(\frac{dx}{-\tau x}\right) e^{-ax} &= -\frac{1}{\tau} \int_{\infty}^0 x^{(\alpha_1 + \alpha_2-1)} e^{-ax} dx \\
&= \frac 1 {\tau} \frac{\Gamma(\alpha_1 + \alpha_2 -1 + 1)}{(y^{\tau} + \delta^{\tau})^{\alpha_1 + \alpha_2 -1+ 1}} \\
&= \frac{1}{\tau} \frac{\Gamma(\alpha_1 + \alpha_2)}{(y^{\tau} + \delta^{\tau})^{\alpha_1 + \alpha_2}}
\end{align*}

as desired.

Comment: Thank you! I forgot to change the integration limits - so I was stuck on what to do with the negative sign!

Comment: You're very welcome.